How to connect microservices swaggers to the spring Cloud Gateway
I want to connect the swaggers of my microservices to the spring cloud gateway. I can do this on localhost and different ports, but as soon as I deploy this to kubernetes, all requests are sent to the host and port of my gateway instead of the host and port of the service itself. Below is the gateway config
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: production
  application:
    name: abs-api-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
#            allow-credentials: true
            allowedMethods:
              - OPTIONS
              - HEAD
              - GET
              - POST
              - PATCH
              - PUT
              - DELETE
      default-filters:
        - StripPrefix=1
        - AddRequestHeader=proxied, true
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE
      ## Routes
      ## Gateway Service Route
      routes[0]:
        id: abs-api-gateway
        uri: ${services.url.gateway-service}
        predicates:
          - Path=/abs/**
      ## User Service Route
      routes[1]:
        id: user-service
        uri: ${services.url.user-service}
        predicates:
          - Path=/user-service/**
        filters:
          - RewritePath=/employees(?<segment>.*),/api/v1/user-service/employees$\{segment}

I tried to write the default host and port, but the gateway does not redirect the request to them
